# is there a script i can use for task scheduler to recycle iis application pool?

Tags: windows, webserver, iis, windows-server

I'm looking into creating a task on one of my servers to recycle the application pool in IIS every night at a certain time automatically. any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Can you write  a command to recycle the application pool? That is, can you do this manually?  If so just create simple task to run a batch command at a certain time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311797/recycle-an-application-pool-using-a-powershell-script

Comment: Are you asking about writing the script, or about creating the scheduled task?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not simply use the recycling setting in iis?
That allows you to recycle every x minutes, at a specific time, based on number of requests or based on memory maximums.